# Event won't fire in event binding for "onblur"

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to get some events to run using knockoutjs and for the life of me cannot figure this out. I've made a simple example to demonstrate the most basic idea of the syntax i am using with no success:

```html
<input type="text" 
       data-bind="event: {onblur: function(){ alert('worked!') }}, 
                  value: signUpModel.fullName, 
                  valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" 
       maxlength="40" 
       id="inputFullName" />
```

Shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will want to just use `blur` instead of `onblur`.  The framework handles it properly depending on whether is uses jQuery to attach the event or does it itself (no jQuery available).

Comment: thanks RP. that was it! Now i've got another problem.. posting now!